# Non-linear xticks spacings in bar plot

Tags: matlab

Is there a way that I can have the `xticks` of my bar plot to have the same spacing even though they are completely non-linear (and non-function related like a logarithmic scale)?

For instance, my `X` vector is

```matlab
>> display (X)

X =
    19  27  28  34  51  52  53  57  66  67  69  73  85  96  105  174  176
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make your `X` data [`categorical`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/categorical.html) (since MATLAB R2013b):

```matlab
X = [19, 27, 28, 34, 51, 52, 53, 57, 176];
Y = randi(100, 1, numel(X));
bar(categorical(X), Y);
```

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I have not accepted your answer nor acknowledged your help (I was going through my Stackoverflow to find some old posts of mine). I'm sorry for that. This directly solved my question